# How to enable bluetooth adapter in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bluetooth

I wanted to disable and enable the bluetooth adapter. So in the system tray I clicked on the Bluetooth icon and in the menu choose for "Turn Adapter Off". I am not sure what happened next but the result was that the bluetooth adapter was no longer showing in the system tray nor the Network settings. So there is no way to enable it again.

I tried reinstalling the drivers but nothing changed. It only told me the drivers were already installed and if I would want to repair or remove them. I tried repairing... nothing. I tried removing and reinstalling... nothing.

Then I went to services and noticed that "Intel Bluetooth Service" was disabled while this was normally enabled. I tried to manually enable the service but it got immediately shut down giving a message that this might happen because it might be in use by other services.

How can I get the bluetooth system tray icon back? and how can I enable the Bluetooth services again? Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a laptop? If so function keys can usually perform secondary functions like enabling/disabling Bluetooth.

Comment: Unfortunately no. To make matters worse the keyboard is connected via bluetooth which does not work anymore, so I am connected via teamviewer to solve it.

Comment: Can you check Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections and see if you can enable Bluetooth adapter there? Also tinkering with driver installs should be your last option in such cases :)

Comment: They used to be there but now they are not. Also reinstalling drivers didn't work. Some service is blocking the bluetooth from enabling =(

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control panel and then devices then you can see your bluetooth adapter. Open it then tick on " lets find other device this computer" and then apply. Now you can connect any bluetooth device to your pc/laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appeared to be a bug in the drivers. After pulling the power cord for 30 seconds and then plugging it back in and restarting the computer. Everything worked again. Sometimes the solution is just that easy.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this today and here's the solution that worked for me:
Go to Device Manager
Look for Bluetooth Radios
Right click on Properties and
Click Enable Device

Answer (score 0):

Go to control panel and click hardware and sound then device manager click on bluetooth radios. Click on Broadcom BCM2070 Bluetooth 2.1......click on Enable.
Exit and Switch off the computer for several minutes. Now restart again.